# How to redirect to URL with fragment? expressjs

Tags: express

How do I achieve the following function in expressjs?

```js
const url = 'https://example.com/a/b#sdjklsfjlkj'
res.redirect(303, url);

// I don't know why frontend fetch only receive a response with url 'https://example.com/a/b';
```

I can manange to do this by using res.json(url). Then redirect to url in frontend part using window.location.url = url.